# Mule AnyPoint DataMapper query

Tags: mule, datamapper, mule-studio

I need to create an o/p JSON in Mule with structure as below. I only get and map value for field 'Field1' from input request (queryParam). I need to additionally create & map (with default values) for the fields - Field211, Field212, Field311, Field312. Their parent elements Field21/Field31 are repeating with fixed counts (3 & 2) respectively. How to achieve this using DataMapper?

```
{
  "Header": {
    "Body": {
      "Field1": "US",
      "Field2": {
        "Field21": [
          {
            "Field211": "1234",
            "Field212": "12345",
          },
          {
            "Field211": "1234",
            "Field212": "12345",
          },
          {
            "Field211": "1234",
            "Field212": "12345",
          },
        ]
      },
      "Field3": {
        "Field31": [
          {
            "Field311": "ABC",
            "Field312": "ABCD",
          },
          {
            "Field311": "ABC",
            "Field312": "ABCD",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just mapping one value here "Field1" from the queryParams to the target JSON field "US". The rest is as you say fixed default values.
You could very easily achieve this using Dataweave as a transformer directly after your HTTP listener with a dw:set-payload like this:

```
    %dw 1.0
    %output application/json
    ---
    {
        Header: {
            Body: {
                Field1: inboundProperties."http.query.params".Field1 as  :string,
                Field2: {
                    Field21: [{
                        Field211: "1234",
                        Field212: "12345"
                    },
                    {
                        Field211: "1234",
                        Field212: "12345"
                    },
                    {
                        Field211: "1234",
                        Field212: "12345"
                    }]
                },
                Field3: {
                    Field31: [{
                        Field311: "ABC",
                        Field312: "ABCD"
                    },
                    {
                        Field311: "ABC",
                        Field312: "ABCD"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```